# Azure DevOps disable Task Insights task failed pop up

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps has added a popup when navigating inside a Build Pipeline to tell you how frequently this step failed in the past.

**Is there a way to disable these pop ups?**  I could close them every time they pop-up, but it's getting disruptive.

[image: annoying popup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Azure DevOps disable Task Insights task failed pop up

This popup also appears when we navigate to the pipeline:

[image]

Currently, I am afraid there is no one effective solution here. The workaround I found for this issue is that **turn off** the Preview features **Multi-stage pipelines**:

[image]

But I don't think it is a solution, just a workaround. Azure devops should provide a feature that we could enable/disable this popup.

So, I open a ticket for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions:

[A feature about enable/disable the Task/pipeline Insights pop up](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/949662/a-feature-about-enabledisable-the-taskpipeline-ins.html)

You can follow with your comments and check the feedback from this ticket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Preview Features menu item is currently available (2020) under the User Settings menu as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#enable-features-for-your-use). Click the person+gear icon in the upper right corner of AzDO, and Preview Features is at the top of its drop-down menu. Then the Task Insights toggle is at the very bottom.

Comment: Can anyone see the point of this popup? Why would I need to know how many times it has failed in a popup like that? The information may be useful, and I may want to look that up, but I don't need it to be announced as I'm debugging a pipeline. It's frustrating enough to see your pipeline fail.

Answer (score 4):

I did it with uBlock Origin, though I suppose that counts as a workaround.